# Как реализовать Drag/Drop файлов из Outlook в приложение на Delphi?

Tags: delphi, drag-n-drop, outlook

Пытаюсь реализовать drag/drop аттачей из outlook в делфи (например путь к файлу вставить в ячейку грида), пробовал реализовать с помощью `IDropTarget`, если перетаскивать из проводника, то все работает, если из почты, то нет. В частности проблема со следующим куском

```
if DataObj.GetData(FmtEtc, Medium) = S_OK then
  // делаем что-то с полученными файлами
```

Вместо `S_OK`, в качестве ответа я получаю `dv_e_formatetc`
Outlook 2010, структура `tagFORMATETC` заполнена следующим образом:

```
  FmtEtc.cfFormat := CF_HDROP;
  FmtEtc.ptd := nil;
  FmtEtc.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
  FmtEtc.lindex := -1;
  FmtEtc.tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;
```

Comment: дак вы там и таскаете не файл в прямом виде, небось?

Comment: Согласно [справке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/objidl/nf-objidl-idataobject-getdata), результат вида `DV_E_FORMATETC` означает, что *The value for **pformatetcIn is not valid.*** Возможно, неправильно заполнена структура `tagFORMATETC`.

Comment: какой версии кстати аутлук используйте?

Comment: @Dima структура tagFORMATETC заполнена следующим образом:

  FmtEtc.cfFormat := CF_HDROP;
  FmtEtc.ptd := nil;
  FmtEtc.dwAspect := DVASPECT_CONTENT;
  FmtEtc.lindex := -1;
  FmtEtc.tymed := TYMED_HGLOBAL;

Comment: @teran Outlook 2010

Comment: Да, я видел это в дополнении в Вашем вопросе. Судя по тому, что имеем: все должно работать. Если есть желание/возможность можете привести в вопросе реализацию интерфейса `IDropTarget`. Возможно, что-то неправильно объявлено, не инициализируется должным образом.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4756845/1216425 ссылка на тему

Comment: @teran читал, делал по аналогии с тем, что писали в комментариях, все равно не работает, возможно проблема в outlook 2010